# In Unity what is the best way of making a robot that has several legs connected with joints move?

Tags: unity, physics, joints, hinge-joint

Here's how the robot looks like in the scene:

[image]

Here's its structure as an object:

[image]

LegX2 is connected to LegX1 with a HingeJoint. LegX1 is connected to Platform with another hinge joint. These two joints have orthogonal axes of rotation.

My goal is to make this robot move by changing the angles of these joints. These joints should therefore behave as servo motors: I set a desired angle, and the motor moves to it.

However this line of thinking doesn't apply in Unity. You can add a motor to a HingeJoint, but it's not a servo motor, but a simple "spin around applying torque" kind. You can set a desired angle, but it's using some kind of spring and I cannot get it to work at all.

What is the best way of achieving what I want? Implementing PID control on top of the Unity motors myself seems frankly absurd. There ought to be a simpler way.

Comment: How about controlling the feet position and let IK deal with moving the legs accordingly?

Comment: [We generally cannot tell you which approach to something in game development is "best"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/best-best-bessssssst-argh). Instead, try to identify the criteria for success we should use for evaluating potential answers. Different games will use different criteria, and arrive at different definitions of "best".

Comment: Do you really want to do this all within Unity? The regular way to create an animated object is to model, rig and animate it in an external 3d modeling program, import it into Unity, add an Animator and AnimatorController to it, and then trigger the animations previously made in the 3d modeling program by setting parameters for the AnimatorController.

Comment: @Philipp Yeah I do, it's important for my use case that there isn't a single animation, but that all of the angles are configurable programmatically. This is more of a simulator than a game. I am asking here because it's highly likely that someone here knows how to do this

Comment: @DMGregory I think I did give a precise description of the outcome I need: I want to cause movement by controlling the angles between leg components and the platform. I have no idea if this is possible, if there is a canonical way of doing this, or if there are multiple ways. I don't even know if HingeJoints are the way to go. Putting "best" in the title might have been a bad choice of words, but I don't think it reflects a serious issue with the question itself.

Comment: As you say, there may be multiple ways to do it. What criteria should we use to rank those ways to select one to share with you?

Comment: @DMGregory The question is vague on that regard because I simply don't know enough about Unity to tell: multiple answers could give different ways of achieving the same result would all be helpful. If one poster knew multiple ways, it would be useful to at least mention them, and pick the simplest one to explain more fully. This is an extremely common situation on StackOverflow for example, where different answers come up with different ideas. In a way if the asker knew how to rank them beforehand he would not be asking the question.

Comment: key word: [Procedural animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_animation). [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/search/?q=Procedural%20animation) are some fantastic demo created by other dudes.